# Why does my code say 109 is not a prime?

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate prime numbers and I almost have it working but for some reason it shows that 109 is not a prime number when 109 is a prime.

So when I output my factorCount it shows "113 :: 29" when 113 is the 30th prime factor and be for it is 107 instead of 109.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mark(bool arr[], int a, int n){
    int i = 2;
    int num = 0;

    while((num = i*a) <= n){
        arr[num-1] = 1;
        i++;
    }
}

void sieve(int n){

    int primeCount = 0;

    if(n >= 2){
        bool arr[n];

        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            if(arr[i] == 0){
                primeCount++;
                cout << i+1 << " :: " << primeCount << endl;

                mark(arr, i+1, n);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int n = 120;

    sieve(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For anyone who's wondering, yes, 109 is prime.

Comment: I smell undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code uses uninitialized variables:

```
bool arr[n];

for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
    if(arr[i] == 0){      // <--- here
```

You check the value of `arr[i]` when you have not set it to anything.

Also, `bool arr[n];` is illegal in C++ although some compilers add it as an extension. In Standard C++, array bounds must be known at compile-time.  To fix it , change `bool arr[n];` to:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> arr(n);  // note: parentheses, not square brackets
```

This version will zero-initialize the members.  Unfortunately `vector<bool>` won't work here as that has a strange specialization. You will need to pass `&arr[0]` to `mark`, rather than just `arr`.

Comment: That is what it was i for got to add this.                         for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
            arr[i] = 0;
        }

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what the problem is with `std::vector<bool>`. It's not beneficial for n=120, but it will work. And if you used n=120'000 then it would be actually a useful specialization.

Comment: @MSalters `vector<bool>` cannot be passed to a function expecting `bool *`

Comment: Well, you'd obviously change that function too. There's nothing weird about a function taking a `std::vector<bool>&`.